# Will supersonic flow return to subsonic through shocks over a flat surface?

Tags: supersonic, fluid-mechanics, shock-waves

Will supersonic flow return to subsonic through shocks over a flat surface? Imagine supersonic flow over a plate. Will it always try to return to subsonic through a series of normal shocks?

(Pretend there’s an infinite plate going supersonic)

I’d imagine over an infinite plate, one shock wouldn’t be enough to eliminate supersonic flow over the rest of the surface, and I always thought if there was supersonic flow a normal shock would try to form.

Comment: If the shock is perpendicular then yes

Comment: @sophit so the flow would turn into a shock? (A perpendicular shock, or normal shock)